# Goolgle App Scripts to QUERY spreadsheet data but permission denied

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a Google App Script which I can make into a slackbot that can query different elements in the sheet.

I'd like to understand why I can't use `setFormula` here. (I had the same issues with `openById` hence why I'm now using `SpreadsheetApp#getActive`.)

> You do not have permission to call setFormula (line 15).

```
function SQL() {
  var spreadsheetId = 'ENTER ID HERE';
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = file.getSheetByName('Data');
  var targetRange = 'Data!A:B';
  var SQL = 'select B where A="Delayed" '
  var Query = '=QUERY(' + targetRange + ',\"' + SQL + '\")'
  var pushQuery = sheet1.getRange(1, 1).setFormula(Query);
  var pullResult = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

  Logger.log(Query);
  Logger.log(pushQuery);
  Logger.log(pullResult);  

  return pushQuery;
  return pullResult;
  return Query;
}
```

Comment: Have you succesfully authorized the script? How/where are you calling the function?

Comment: @FatFingersJackson yes I authorized it - Unsure it's designed that way when calling SpreadSheetApp

Comment: Custom functions can only read other cells in the same workbook, and only cells in which their `return` value will expand into can be modified. Review basic fundamentals of [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). Also review the JavaScript fundamentals on how `return` statement affects function execution.